# Reset ninja form fields after bootstrap modal close

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, ninja-forms

I have modal with ninja form inside:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="vakancesModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="vakancesModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body sazinaties-ar-mums-form">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[ninja_form id=5]') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want on modal close reset form with jquery or javascript

```
$('#vakancesModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
 
//nija form reset js or jquery

});
```

Ninja form documentation is very poor, so I can not find any solution to reset form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#vakancesModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
     //nija form reset js or jquery
     jQuery('#nf-form-5-cont form').attr("style", "display: inline !important");
     jQuery('.nf-response-msg').attr("style", "display: none !important");
});
```

Comment: yes, you are right, I have already tried this option. But here the form does not reload, and if the user has submited it and received success message or there are incorrectly filled fields, then all this remains. And this case only working on input fields.

Comment: can you please send form page link so will check and add code

Comment: please add the new code and let know its working or not.

Comment: add this code and sorry for wrong understanding of your problem.